# @ManyToOne is not persisting the Parent FKey column in the Child table

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, spring-batch

The join below is persisting the TaxJurisdictions related to each client, but it`s not including the Column used in the Join (CLIENT_CODE) in the insert, resulting in null in my database table TBL_TAX_JURISDICTION.CLIENT_CODE. How can I change this setup in order to persists the client code with its tax jurisdictons?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_TAX_JURISDICTION")
@XmlRootElement(name="taxJurisdiction")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TaxJurisdiction {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn(name="CLIENT_CODE", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true)
    private Clients clients;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String Id;
....
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_CLIENTS")
@XmlRootElement(name = "client")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Clients extends Feed {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="taxJurisdictions")
    @XmlElement(name="taxJurisdiction")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "clients", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TaxJurisdiction> taxJurisdictions = new ArrayList<>();


    @Id
    @Column
    @XmlElement(name = "CLIENT_CODE")
    private String CLIENT_CODE;

    public List<TaxJurisdiction> getTaxJurisdictions() {
        return new ArrayList<>(taxJurisdictions);
    }

    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` from `TaxJurisdiction`. You should not cascade any operation on TaxJurisdiction to clients. Also, if you don't really need it to lazy, remove `fetch` too. The following code works fine in my test

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CLIENT_CODE", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true)
private Clients clients;
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work, the CLIENT_CODE is still being populated as null in my TAX_JURISDICTION table. And if I set nullable=false my code fails: `nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value`

Comment: Does your `TaxJurisdiction` have a clients with valid CLIENT_TOKEN? And is that client in the db?

Comment: Yes, the CLIENT_CODE is a valid one. The client is being insert into the DB at the same time of TaxJurisdiction. Once my code runs it results in both tables with entries, but the CLIENT_CODE in my TaxJurisdiction table is null.

Comment: Can you do the flow I tested with - 1. Create a client. 2. Persist it. 3.Create a tax jurisdiction and set the previous client to it. 4. Persis the tax jurisdiction.

If it still doesn't work, share the part of your code when you save tax jurisdiction.